# Issue with SSL connection to IBM WEB MQ

Tags: c#, ssl, ssl-certificate, ibm-mq

I'm trying to connect with ssl "Required" channel with c#.net application.
 I followed below steps to create and exchange the certificates

With the help of IBM key management tool I created self-signed certificate in websphere MQ server (192.168.10.2)
 then extracted it as server.arm

[image]

Then did the same things for client side

[image]

After that I copied server.arm to client machine (192.168.10.1) and client.arm to WMQ server (192.168.10.2)

In server's IBM key management tool I selected signer certificates and added client.arm I set the label name as ibmwebspheremqclient
 then in client machine (192.168.10.1) I added server.arm as signer certificate and set label as ibmwebspheremqqm_sslconnect

Here is my channel configuration. If I set this setting as optional then this is working fine for me but I must have to enable SSL option as "Required".

[image]

[image]

when I tried to connect with this code block

```
using IBM.WMQ;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

    public class SSLConnectionTest
        {
            const String connectionType = IBM.WMQ.MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_CLIENT;
            const String qManager = "QM_SSLConnect";
            const String hostName = "192.168.10.2";
            const String channel = "ADMIN.TLS.SVRCONN";
            const String port = "1480";
            const String sslKeyRepository = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ\ssl\key";
            const String cipherSpec = "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256";
            const String cipherSuite = "SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256";

            public Hashtable init()
            {
                Hashtable properties = new Hashtable();

                properties.Add(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_CLIENT);
                properties.Add(MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, hostName);
                properties.Add(MQC.PORT_PROPERTY, port);
                properties.Add(MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, channel);

                properties.Add(MQC.SSL_CERT_STORE_PROPERTY, sslKeyRepository);
                properties.Add(MQC.SSL_CIPHER_SUITE_PROPERTY, cipherSuite);
                properties.Add(MQC.SSL_CIPHER_SPEC_PROPERTY, cipherSpec);

                return properties;
            }

            public void TestSSLConnection()
            {
                try
                {
                    Hashtable connectionProperties = init();
                    MQQueueManager qMgr = new MQQueueManager(qManager, connectionProperties);

                }
                catch (MQException ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("A WebSphere MQ error occurred: {0}", ex.ToString());
                }
                catch (System.Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("A System error occurred: {0}", ex.ToString());
                }
            }

        }
```

it gives me this error code 
[image]

I already refreshed REFRESH SECURITY TYPE(SSL)

I found following errors in my client (192.168.10.1) C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ\errors\AMQERR01.LOG 
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1gc0AoxQpdLNg1pz_vkw-tapWDNclYXY5ql_aMIVBMfA/edit?usp=sharing

and my server's 192.168.10.2 error log
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1lxzo41TWauAyYKH1wcXOxj6HYlTYkSUoPjaTmsJHxYI/edit?usp=sharing

Can anyone help me ???

Comment: If any one interested with this , here I have posted how I achieved this  http://2freeclear.wordpress.com/2014/11/29/transport-level-security-with-ibm-websphere-mq-in-net-environment/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The errors in the AMQERR01.LOG files are telling you that the client side certificate is not being picked up. The label should be `ibmwebspheremq<client-logged-on-user>`

From your screen shots I can see that your certificate label is `ibmwebspheremqclient` but from the screen shot of the command prompt it appears your logged on user ID might actually be `herath`, in which case the MQ code will be looking for a certificate label `ibmwebspheremqherath`, not finding it and so going anonymous.

Rename the label of your client side certificate to the appropriate label and see if it now picks it up.

Comment: ohh Morag nice to see you back It is working You are an IBM WMQ angel thanks for saving me from this ssl misery.

Comment: both of you are working for IBM ryt??? It is really hard to find good tutorials for web sphere IBM MQ for beginners like us. When it comes to .NET it is much more difficult to get help. Most of IBM document also focuses on java and C. So I kindly asking you two , to publish some basic tutorials on Triggering, Transport level security, message level security + AMS and other interesting things that we can do with IBM WMQ. Thank you.

Comment: Well, Shashi is the .Net MQ guru of all time! And I agree that Morag ls an IBM MQ angel. However, may I humbly suggest that you drop by at https://t-rob.net/links where I've published many articles and tutorials on TLS (including a full copy of the first MQ SSL Lab from the IMPACT conference)?  Usually these are inspired by situations from my consulting clients but I'm always happy to take topic suggestions. Better yet, post a question here and contact me through the blog or at the email in my profile to make sure I see it.

Comment: Also, go to http://www.capitalware.com/ and look for the "Downloads" section in the navigation on the left side. Click on the platform of interest and it pops up a bunch of links, including many leading to sample source code.

Comment: Tutorial on triggering: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/1103_mismes/1103_mismes.html